# Dealing with screen resolutions in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I’m sure this question has probably been asked before…

Right now i am porting my game over from Android. right now i have cocos2d fully integrated and i am ready to go. But i want to make sure i understand how the scaling works..

In Android you just provide a width and height for the scene and the graphics are scaled up or down based on the device.

From reading, it doesnt seem to work that way on IOS. So how do you design for screen resolutions such as the 3g, 4,5 and ipad devices?

I was reading, and i know its a best practice to not hard code screen coordinates. With this being said, it seems like the only thing that would need to be scaled would be the background image of the game?

Maybe im wrong, Im kinda of confused about how it works.

If someone could explain that would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Cocos2D, images are selected automatically based on their associated prefix: `name.png` for non-retina deivces, `name-hd.png` for retina, `name-ipad.png` for ipad 1 and mini, and `name-ipadhd.png` for ipad retina.

For scaling, I have some useful defines that will allow you to alter things based on the particular platform:

```
#define MIDSCREEN  ccp([CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.width/2, [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.height/2)
#define WINSIZE [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize]
#define WINHEIGHT [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].height
#define WINWIDTH [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width
#define IS_IPAD() (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_RETINA() (CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() == 2)
#define REAL_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() (CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() * (IS_IPAD() + 1))
#define CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() (IS_IPAD() ? 2.0 : CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR())
#define IPAD_SCALE() (IS_IPAD() ? 2.0 : 1.0)
#define CCP_IPAD(___X___, ___Y___) (IS_IPAD() ? ccp((___X___ + 16.0f) * CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR(), (___Y___ + 32.0f) * CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR()) : ccp(___X___, ___Y___))
#define CCP_IPHONE(___X___, ___Y___) (IS_IPAD() ? ccp(___X___, ___Y___) : ccp((___X___ / 2.0) - 16.0f, (___Y___ / 2.0) - 32.0f))
#define IS_IPHONE5() ([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width == 568 || [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].height == 568)
```